# How to add hyperlink to a Java SWT Label

Tags: java, swt

I have a  `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label` and I want to add a Hyperlink to a specific portion of the Label Text. For example to have something like: "Click **HERE**" and when I click on **HERE** then a specific window will open.

If it doesn't work with the Label, then what else can I use to have a Hyperlink? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`Label` is just plain text.

The `Link` class (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link`) allows text and links. The Javadoc for `Link.setText` says:

> The string can contain both regular text and hyperlinks. A hyperlink
>   is delimited by an anchor tag, <a> and </a>. Within an anchor, a
>   single HREF attribute is supported. When a hyperlink is selected, the
>   text field of the selection event contains either the text of the
>   hyperlink or the value of its HREF, if one was specified. In the rare
>   case of identical hyperlinks within the same string, the HREF
>   attribute can be used to distinguish between them. The string may
>   include the mnemonic character and line delimiters. The only delimiter
>   the HREF attribute supports is the quotation mark ("). Text containing
>   angle-bracket characters < or > may be escaped using \, however this
>   operation is a hint and varies from platform to platform.

You must listen to the selection event from this control and add code to open the link.

In an Eclipse plug-in you can use the Eclipse Forms `FormText` and `Hyperlink` controls which also allow mixed text and links plus other formatting.